# Displaying Result from SQL Server database using datalist control in asp.net consume time

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

I have 3 radiobuttons `Business, Contact, Adresss`

Three DataList :

1. `Business`: shows CompanyName, Employee Name, EmailID, Contact, Website address
2. `Contact`: shows Employee Name, Contact
3. `Address`: EmaiID, CompayName, Website address

On check of RadioButton I show respective datalist.

I had records > 1000 rows for DataList `Business`, when I check radiobuttons it takes time to show result

What should I do to make my application run smoothly and fast? I am using Alphabet paging also to show DataList result alphabetically.I want to show more then 1000 records at a time may be records can be >5000 or more

This is my stored procedure :

```
if(@type = 'Business')
begin
    if(@Utype  ='1' )
    begin
        IF (@Alphabet = 'A' and @name = '' and @company = '' ) 
        BEGIN
           SELECT  
               Company, Address, CardDetail.Name, Email, Mobile, Telephone, Fax, Web, Job, 1, createdby
           FROM 
               CardDetail   
           WHERE 
               Company LIKE 'A%' 
               AND (ViewType = 'C' OR ViewType = 'A' OR createdby = @uid) 
        END

        IF (@Alphabet <> 'A' AND @name = '' AND @company = '') 
        BEGIN
            SELECT  
               Company, Address, Name, Email, Mobile, Telephone, Fax, Web, Job, 2, createdby
            FROM 
               CardDetail  
            WHERE 
               Company LIKE @Alphabet + '%' 
               AND (ViewType = 'C' OR ViewType = 'A' OR createdby = @uid) 
            ORDER BY
               Company ASC
        END

        IF (@name <> '' and @company <> '')
        begin
           SELECT DISTINCT 
              Company, Address, Name, Email, Mobile, Telephone, Fax, Web, Job, 3, createdby 
           FROM 
              CardDetail  
           WHERE 
              Company = @company 
              AND Name = @name  
              AND (ViewType = 'C' OR ViewType = 'A' OR createdby = @uid) 
           ORDER BY 
              Company ASC
end
```

THIS IS CODE BEHIND : 
//Alphabet Paging and LinkButton :

```
       protected void Alphabet_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
      LinkButton lnkAlphabetID = (LinkButton)sender;
      ViewState["CurrentAlphabet"] = lnkAlphabetID.Text;
       this.GenerateAlphabets();
       this.BindDataList("");
     }

     private void GenerateAlphabets()
    {
        List<Alphabet> alphabets = new List<Alphabet>();
        Alphabet alphabet = new Alphabet();
        alphabet.Value = "A";
        alphabet.isNotSelected = !alphabet.Value
                    .Equals(ViewState["CurrentAlphabet"]);
        alphabets.Add(alphabet);

        for (int i = 66; i <= 90; i++)
        {
            alphabet = new Alphabet();
            alphabet.Value = Char.ConvertFromUtf32(i);
            alphabet.isNotSelected = !alphabet.Value
                    .Equals(ViewState["CurrentAlphabet"]);
            alphabets.Add(alphabet);
        }
        rptAlphabets.DataSource = alphabets;
        rptAlphabets.DataBind();
    }
```

DataList Binding : // rb1,rb2,rb3 are radiobuttons

```
     private void BindDataList(string type)
    {
      if (type=="")
        {
            if (rb1.Checked == true)
                type = "Business";
            else if (rb2.Checked == true)
                type = "Address";
            else if (rb3.Checked == true)
                type = "Contact";
        }
        string Type = type;
        string name = "";
        string company = "";

        string conStr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["cnSting_Con"].ConnectionString;
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(conStr);
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("[spx_GetBusiness]");
        cmd.Connection = con;
        con.Open();
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Alphabet", ViewState["CurrentAlphabet"]);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@type", type);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@name", name);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@company", company);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Utype", Session["Type"].ToString());
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@uid", Session["user_id"].ToString());
        DataTable ds = new DataTable();
        SqlDataAdapter sd = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
        sd.Fill(ds);
        con.Close();

        if (type == "Business")
        {
            Business.DataSource = ds;
            Business.DataBind();
          }
```

On Page Load

```
     protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

                Business.Visible = false;
                Address.Visible = false;
                Contact.Visible = false;
                dl_company.Visible = false; 
                ViewState["CurrentAlphabet"] = "A";
                this.GenerateAlphabets();
     }
```

Comment: Is it the query that's slow? or the actual Web UI? `C#` code?

Comment: You should start by profiling the SQL and seeing how long the queries take via *SSMS*.

Comment: Start Time : 2014-10-25 14:04:13.960

End Time : 2014-10-25 14:04:13.973 

Total : 13ms